# Updating unpermitted values in an Ecto changeset

Tags: phoenix-framework, ecto

I want to update some meta data that is not a `permitted` attribute in my schema's changeset:

```
def changeset(%Comment{} = comment, attrs) do
  comment
  |> cast(attrs, [:text])
  |> validate_required([:text])
end
```

And then something like:

```
changeset = Comment.changeset(commet, %{under_moderation: true})

Repo.update(changeset)
```

Since `under_moderation` is not whitelisted, it gets ignored. What options do I have to force the update? If there are multiple options, is there a convention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just create another changeset function that has the rights to set the value.

```
def admin_changeset(%Comment{} = comment, attrs) do
  comment
  |> cast(attrs, [:text, :under_moderation])
  |> validate_required([:text])
end
```

Then simply use that to update the value. As you can see, I named it `admin_changeset` because it seems like this is a value that would be set by an admin. In your controller or context module, simply check the user role (if you have something like that) and then decide which changeset function you want to use.

Comment: Thank you! That makes a lot of sense.